# using Datavalue / Extracting selected "Tag"'s value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I grab the selected `datavalue` property in javascript without using `onClick`. I have multiple spans that have the same class, etc; except `datavalue`.

**HTML**

```
<span class="sku">
       <span class="imgsku">
         <a class="colourBox" datavalue="thisValue">
              <p>Test</p>
       </a>
 </span>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {
    $(".sku a").click(function() {
        var obj = this;
        //Update Hidden Field after retrieving the selected value
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "except datavalue" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this attribute `data-value` and this code :

```
$('a.colourBox').each(function(){
    var value = $(this).data('value');
});
```

This will loop on each link with `colourBox` class on DOM ready.

Comment: Thanks! Straight forward enough :D

Answer (score 1):

You miss the dash '-' between data and value

```
<span class="sku">
       <span class="imgsku">
         <a class=" colourBox"  data-value="thisValue">
              <p>Test</p>
       </a>
</span>
```

To get the value

```
$(function() {
    $(".sku a").click(function() {
        var value = ( this ).data( "value" )
        //Update hidden field after retrieving the selected value
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to adjust your html to use the `data` attribute properly.

it should be `data-value = "somevalue"`

Then the corresponding **jQuery** function to grab your data value is:

```
var yourValue = $(this).data('value');
```

For more about the proper usage of jQuery's `.data()` function you can read up on it here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/

For more info about the proper usage of HTML's `data` attribute, you can read up more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Here is proper **Javascript** usage:

***HTML***

```
<a id="someLink" data-value="thisValue">Link</a>
```

***Javascript***

```
var dataval = document.querySelector('#someLink').dataset.value;
```